# Unable to save file into Download folder of a window machine using c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, itext, hosting

I have created a dll that generates pdf and downloads the result into **Downloads folder** of my local machine, but when i am hosting the application into the server its does not returning **path to download folder** nor any pdf files.

i have tried different ways to save the files but its not working.

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(report, new FileStream(DownloadPath.getDownloadFolderPath() + "/" + reportName, FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Do you get exception? add try/catch blocks and see the error.

Comment: What user does your program run as on the server? If it is running as a local service or system it might not have a downloads folder to save to.